# Calculating pi with a non-random circular walk in python

Tags: python, pi

**Why is the following method gererating 2*sqrt(2) instead of pi?**

I'm trying to iterate by one step either in the x or y direction by following a circular path for 90 degrees. Once done, I can calculate pi by dividing by radius. But I keep getting 2.8 instead of 3.14.

Code:

```
import math
circ=1
res=1000000
x=res
y=0
while x>=y:
    circ=circ+1
    ops=[]
    ops.append(abs(res**2 - (x-1)**2 - (y+0)**2))
    ops.append(abs(res**2 - (x-0)**2 - (y+1)**2))
    ops.append(abs(res**2 - (x-1)**2 - (y+1)**2))
    ops.append(abs(res**2 - (x+1)**2 - (y+1)**2))
    ops.append(abs(res**2 - (x-1)**2 - (y-1)**2))
    o= ops.index(min(ops))
    #print(o,ops)
    if o==0: x=x-1
    if o==1: y=y+1
    if o==2: x=x-1; y=y+1
    if o==3: x=x+1; y=y+1
    if o==4: x=x-1; y=y-1
print(x,y)
print()
print(circ*4/res)
```

output

```
707106 707108

2.828436

[Program finished]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1DqY.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no question here and it's not clear what exactly you need help with. If you're looking for debugging help, you might check out [How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](/q/4929251/4518341), [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and [mre].

Comment: The question is: why is the algorithm I'm using generating 2*sqrt(2) instead of pi?

Comment: That's not the sort of question we can answer very well, unfortunately. Either the algorithm is wrong or it's been implemented incorrectly. We'd need something more specific to provide a substantial answer (i.e. not just "you made a typo here" or that sort of thing). If I were you, first I'd check that the code matches the algorithm description (assuming it was written down in math terms originally).

Comment: Can you explain what you *think* your program is doing right now? You have a list called `ops` that gets generated every single loop iteration, then you ignore all of its elements and just find the minimum and use that to dispatch some other behavior. I have no earthly idea what that array is, the variable name `ops` isn't doing it any favors, and there's no comments explaining the otherwise unintuitive behavior. If you want others to debug your code, you're going to have to make an effort to explain what it does.

Comment: Always using `circ += 1` is not correct.  When *both* x and y are changed, it should be `circ += math.sqrt(2)`.

Comment: "The question is: why is the algorithm I'm using generating 2*sqrt(2) instead of pi?" You first: step by step, **why should it** compute pi? How do you intend for that to work? (It seems like you fundamentally have a question that's purely about the math, rather than programming. The approach you're describing fundamentally cannot compute pi, because limits do not work that way. Honestly, without tracing through it more carefully, I would have [expected a result of 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906) instead.)

Answer (score 2):

Let `r` be the radius of the circle. You are traveling along the circle from the point `(r, 0)` to the point of the circle where coordinates are equal. This point is `(r/sqrt(2), r/sqrt(2))`. At each step you are moving either one unit horizontally, vertically, or across the diagonal of a unit square. `circ` is the number of steps you take along the way. Since the radius of the circle is large compared to the length of each step, `circ` will be close to
`max(abs(r - r/sqrt(2)), abs(0 - r/sqrt(2)))` i.e. the larger of the horizontal and vertical distances between the two points. This maximum is equal to `abs(0 - r/sqrt(2)) = r/sqrt(2)`. As a result `(4 * circ)/r = 4/sqrt(2) = 2*sqrt(2)`.